Force Qt Creator's Code_completion overwrites instead of inserts
could you please tell - is it possible to force Qt Creator's Code_completion to overwrite existing code instead of inserts new code in front of old text/code.
Exactly the way how is done in Eclipse (screenshot is attached).

I searched QtCreator's preferences (v14), googled, but didn't find a piece of useful.
